# Max size of filter_script file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using the following command to successfully extract a list of frames from videos. I tried to use it to extract 12,227 frames and the command exits without generating any frames and error messages. I suspect there may be a limit on the size of the filter script file but can't seem to find what is the limit and how to increase it. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_script:v Frames.txt -vsync 0 -video-%06d.jpg`

content of Frames.txt file is:

```
select='eq(n,70)
+eq(n,108)
+eq(n,183)
+eq(n,191)
+eq(n,197)
..... etc
+eq(n,18948)
'
```

Comment: I suggest you examine the source code to find the limits. [Download FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've never worked with the source code but will try.

Comment: @DavidPostill I downloaded the source but I'm having trouble finding the file(s) where the max size of the script file would be defined. Any direction or suggestions you could provide would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to look for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill not asking you to look. Just thought you might be familiar with the source and might be able to suggest roughly where to look.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the source.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might get more help if your title was: `ffmpeg: extract frames and the command exits without generating any frames or error messages`

Comment: Search for: `ffmpeg extract frames and the command exits without generating any frames or error messages`